# Facebook Email Permissions

Tags: facebook, email, permissions

We are doing an app for facebook & we are  requested permission for grab his information,

Now the problem  is that we need the `user e-mail id` is show in our data or console.(There show the users all details like First_name, last_name, gender, education, id , etc..)

We are use this code:

```
else
{
    NSArray* _permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email",@"user_birthday",@"publish_stream",nil];
    [appDelegate.Facebook  authorize:_permissions delegate:self appAuth:NO safariAuth:NO];
}
```

Is there any other way to show the e-mail now? What should I do?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. But here's a shot: Yes, you MUST request `email` in order to view their email. Use the `/me?fields=email` endpoint after the authorization to get their email.

Comment: I am asking  show the email or email permission. I have show  all the user (Facebook login user) data except email.I have check the permission but there are lock the email.